# Use correctly GPS in a service "Activate and disable automatically using the actual speed"

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gps, android-service

In a service: What I want is that the GPS request the speed only one time every 10-15 minutes, and if the actual speed that catch is higher than X value, the refresh time change from 15 minutes to as fast as the GPS can. For the momento i have this:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener,LocationListener {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    time = High_Refresh;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, 0, this); //GPS_Provider
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Actual_Speed = location.getSpeed();
    if (Actual_Speed >= Speed_Value_Change) {
        if (d == 0) {
            enjegarAccelerometre();
        }
        d = De_Rapid_A_Lent;
        time = High_Refresh;
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, 0, this);
        //notificacioProva("2","3","4");

    } else {

        if (d == 0) 
            {
                time = Low_Refresh;
                pararAccelerometre();
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, 0, this);
            } 
            else 
            {
                d--;
            }
    }
    Last_Speed=Actual_Speed;
}

}
```

But with this code, I think that the GPS is runing all the time "The Position sensor apear always on the top"

Can I make this by another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need LocationManager to return just a single Location object, then use  requestSingleUpdate(), then onLocationChanged() would be called just once.

And in the period of time, when you want to receive speed as often as GPS can,
requestLocationUpdates() is a right method.

And remember to always call  removeUpdates(listener) on LocationManager when you don't need to obtain Location data no more, since listening for updates  consumes a lot of battery.